# htaccess - how to find last hyphen

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two types of URLs without page number:
http://example.com/promotional-pens-and-pencils
and with it
http://example.com/promotional-pens-and-pencils-p2

So far I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^promotional-(*)$ /section.php?xName=promotional-$1 [QSA,L]
```

And here I need help

```
RewriteRule ^promotional-()-p([0-9]*)$ /section.php?xName=promotional-$1&xPage=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^promotional-(.*)-p([0-9]+)/?$ /section.php?xName=promotional-$1&xPage=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^promotional-(.*)/?$ /section.php?xName=promotion-$1 [QSA,L]
```